# TLS1.2 connection from native Android app to Worklight server using wlclient library

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, tls1.2

I am using wlclient.jar for making a connection to Worklight server from Android native app but my requirement is to make it TLS1.2 connection only . I dont find any API in wlclient.jar for mentioning TLS1.2 as a security level . IS customizing wlclient.jar is the only option ? if yes what changes I need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has since become an APAR (support ticket) for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1: [PI64093: APPS ON ANDROID VERSIONS 4.4.2 AND EARLIER CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER USING HTTPS IF ONLY TLS 1.2 IS ENABLED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI64093).

Workaround (from the APAR description):

> In the native Android code of the MobileFirst Platform hybrid
>   application, in the "onCreate()" method in the application's
>   main activity, it is possible to replace the default
>   SSLSocketFactory provided by Android with one that enables TLS
>   1.2, immediately after the call to "WL.createInstance(this)",
>   in order to accommodate the use of TLS 1.2 with Android
>   versions 4.4.2 and earlier.  Specific steps and code to
>   accomplish this are beyond the scope of this APAR.

There is now an iFix available to download from IBM Fix Central.

> The issue is resolved by programmatically enabling TLS on
>   Android devices with OS <4.2.